Exponential Pauli matrix identity query
Just a quick question, is it clear to anyone how the following identity follows $$\text{exp}[-i(\pi/2)\hat{S_y}] = (I-\hat{S_{+}}+\hat{S_{-}})/ \sqrt{2},$$ where $I$ is the identity and $\hat{S_{+}}$ and $\hat{S_{-}}$ are the raising and lowering operators respectively. This is stated on page 2, below equation (4) of this paper. Using the Euler formula for matrices I obtain the following equation $$\text{exp}[-i(\pi/2)\hat{S}_y] = \cos(\pi/2)-i \sin(\pi/2)\hat{S}_y = -i\hat{S_{y}}.$$ This is not equal to the RHS of the equation where $\hat{S_{+}} = \hat{S_x}+i\hat{S_y}$ and $\hat{S_{-}} = \hat{S_x}-i\hat{S_y} \implies $ RHS = $(I-2i\hat{S_y})/\sqrt{2}$.

Interesting, I never thought about such formulas as generalizations of Euler's formula.

Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

For spin $1/2$ operators, we have $\left(\hat{S}_y\right) ^2=1/4$. Thus, the correct version of your formula would be
$$
\exp(-i(\pi/2)\hat{S}_y) = \exp(-i(\pi/4)(2\hat{S}_y)) = \cos(\pi/4) - i\sin(\pi/4)(2\hat{S}_y) =
$$
$$
= (I - \hat{S}_+ + \hat{S}_-)/\sqrt{2}.
$$
